# clearing timer value with clearInterval before initializing the timer

Tags: javascript, timer

while googling for some content i found this code.

```
clearInterval(slip.timer);    
slip.timer = setInterval(function () { mv(target, direction); }, 15);
```

My doubt is first we need to set timer with setInterval then clear it with clearInterval.Here how can we use slip.timer even before it's initialization?
can anyone help me?
In which applications do we code like this?

Answer (score 6):

So long as `slip` is initialised by the time this code runs, it is fine.  Calling `clearInterval` with a value that's not a valid interval ID (eg `undefined` or `null` if `slip.timer` not been set yet) is defined behaviour, as per [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-clearinterval):

> The clearTimeout() and clearInterval() methods must clear the entry
>   identified as handle from the list of active timers of the
>   WindowTimers object on which the method was invoked, if any, where
>   handle is the argument passed to the method. (**If handle does not
>   identify an entry in the list of active timers of the WindowTimers
>   object on which the method was invoked, the method does nothing.**)

(emphasis mine)

This is a fairly common approach when the timer could be triggered several times to ensure you don't have multiple copies of the interval timer calling your callback - if there's a chance it's going to happen, you want to make sure you clear the previous interval before starting a new one.

Comment: as these timers belong to window,can we set timer in one function and clear in another function

Comment: So long as you have a reference to the handle returned by `setInterval`/`setTimeout`, yes - that can be passed around and passed to `clearInterval`/`clearTimeout` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It’s useful to clear a `setTimeout` or a `setInterval` before starting a new one if those timers are being used multiple times.

Consider this example: you have a stop watch that starts from 0. You start it and the numbers increase. Now you want to reset the stop watch and still have it running (e. g. noting the time of a completed lap). You could have a single function that does the following to accomplish this:

1. Set the timer to 0
2. Start it with `setInterval`

If you ran this function twice — i. e. one initial start and then a reset — , there would be ***two*** interval timers set as opposed to **one**. Thus the stop watch will run ***twice as fast***. This is undesired behavior and therefore the function should instead do these steps:

1. Stop the current interval timer with `clearInterval` if there is one
2. Set the timer to 0
3. Start it with `setInterval`

As James Thorpe pointed out, an `undefined` or `null` reference passed to `clearInterval` is not a big deal.

If you want to be safe about clearing something before it has been intitialized however you can simply intialize that something:

```
var slip = {
    timer: 0
  };

// … Later:
clearInterval(slip.timer);
```

Or you could test whether that something exists:

```
if(window.slip && slip.timer){
  clearInterval(slip.timer);
}
```

Or if your code is in a closure and `slip` isn’t defined globally:

```
if(typeof slip !== "undefined" && slip.timer){
  clearInterval(slip.timer);
}
```

Comment: as these timers belong to window,can we set timer in one function and clear timer in another function